# Random Numbers Generator based on Current Time and Birth Date

Tags: javascript, random, numbers, generator, seed

I am starting to learn JavaScript and I found this article: http://michalbe.blogspot.ro/2011/02/javascript-random-numbers-with-custom.html

I liked the idea of a custom seed number generator but I for the love of Thor cannot figure it out, I really need a practical example done with pure javascript or a library like jQuery if it's easier.

### Here we go:

So what I want is to generate 10 different numbers sepparated by "-" (minus), each number with the range of 1-50 and I would like the seed for each number to be made up by multiplying 2 things:

1. the current time in as much as a bigger number sequence as you can get it (with a delay of 1 second for each number so the time will be different)
2. your birth date (from 3 select inputs)

**[!]** Also I want to know how we can animate the generation of these 10 numbers in different ways, like... for example the animation of old train station Arival/Departures mechanical displays, or like different HTML5 canvas particle techniques or CSS3 or anything really. - This can be done in another question if you think it's too much.

If you are able to help me out with this I will be so very forever grateful!

Thank you!

```js
var CustomRandom = function(nseed) {    
  
  var seed,    
    constant = Math.pow(2, 13)+1,    
    prime = 1987,    
//any prime number, needed for calculations, 1987 is my favorite:)  
    maximum = 50;    
//maximum number needed for calculation the float precision of the numbers (10^n where n is number of digits after dot)  
    if (nseed) {    
      seed = nseed;    
    }    
    
    if (seed == null) {    
//before you will correct me in this comparison, read Andrea Giammarchi's text about coercion http://goo.gl/N4jCB  
      
      seed = (new Date()).getTime();   
//if there is no seed, use timestamp     
    }     
    
    return {    
      next : function(min, max) {    
        seed *= constant;    
        seed += prime;    
           
      
        return min && max ? min+seed%maximum/maximum*(max-min) : seed%maximum/maximum;  
// if 'min' and 'max' are not provided, return random number between 0 & 1  
      }    
    }    
}

var rng = CustomRandom(09031887);
//use '09031887' as a seed ?
    rng.next();
    rng.next();
});
```

```html
<b>Your birth date:</b><br>
Day: 
<select id="day">
<option selected="selected">01</option>
<option>02</option><option>03</option><option>04</option><option>05</option><option>06</option><option>07</option><option>08</option><option>09</option><option>10</option><option>11</option><option>12</option><option>13</option><option>14</option><option>15</option><option>16</option><option>17</option><option>18</option><option>19</option><option>20</option><option>21</option><option>22</option><option>23</option><option>24</option><option>25</option><option>26</option><option>27</option><option>28</option><option>29</option><option>30</option><option>31</option>
</select>
Month:
<select id="month">
<option selected="selected">01</option>
<option>02</option><option>03</option><option>04</option><option>05</option><option>06</option><option>07</option><option>08</option><option>09</option><option>10</option><option>11</option><option>12</option>
</select>
Year: 
<select id="year">
<option selected="selected">1998</option>
<option>1997</option><option>1996</option><option>1995</option><option>1994</option><option>1993</option><option>1992</option><option>1991</option><option>1990</option><option>1989</option><option>1988</option><option>1987</option><option>1986</option><option>1985</option><option>1984</option><option>1983</option><option>1982</option><option>1981</option><option>1980</option><option>1979</option><option>1978</option><option>1977</option><option>1976</option><option>1975</option><option>1976</option><option>1975</option><option>1976</option>
</select>
<br><br>

<span id="nr1"></span> - 
<span id="nr2"></span> - 
<span id="nr3"></span> - 
<span id="nr4"></span> - 
<span id="nr5"></span> - 
<span id="nr6"></span> - 
<span id="nr7"></span> - 
<span id="nr8"></span> - 
<span id="nr9"></span> - 
<span id="nr10"></span>
<br><br>

<button>Generate</button>
```

Comment: where exactly is the problem? what did you try so far? post a jsfiddle

Comment: Creating a random integer in a range is simple [Math.random](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random), but as you can see there is no way of controlling the `seed` with this built in function. This is also true for the modern [Crypto.getRandomValues](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RandomSource/getRandomValues) If a `seed` is a must then you will have to look at a 3rd party library (or write it yourself).

Comment: I have not yet managed to make the one in the article work, so I don't have anything really, all I have is some HTML for the output. This is why I asked for a practical example :(

Comment: Show us your code that you were unable to get to work, and what appeared to be going wrong, then we can give you advice on how to correct it.

Comment: Here is what I have: https://jsfiddle.net/cunuqq7h/

Comment: I've also found this: https://github.com/davidbau/seedrandom but I don't know how to apply it.

Comment: The first thing that I notice with the code that you have provided is, in the [console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/console) it shows `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }` You also have no [event handling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) for the supplied HTML.

Comment: The project https://github.com/davidbau/seedrandom gives examples of how to implement the library, they seems concise and reasonable.

Comment: Well as long as the script works even without event handlers, I would be happy. I can provide values from the select inputs and change the value of variables later on.

Comment: I would not like to use a whole library for this, but if I can see a practical example of implementing that library I would consider it of course.

Answer (score 0):

If you fix the `SyntaxError` in your supplied code, then the Javascript code actually works. You don't have any event handlers to control it with your supplied HTML though.

```js
var CustomRandom = function (nseed) {
    var seed,
        constant = Math.pow(2, 13) + 1,
        prime = 1987,
        //any prime number, needed for calculations, 1987 is my favorite:)  
        maximum = 50;
        //maximum number needed for calculation the float precision of the numbers (10^n where n is number of digits after dot)  
    
    if (nseed) {
        seed = nseed;
    }

    if (seed == null) {
        //before you will correct me in this comparison, read Andrea Giammarchi's text about coercion http://goo.gl/N4jCB  
        seed = (new Date()).getTime();
        //if there is no seed, use timestamp     
    }

    return {
        next: function (min, max) {
            seed *= constant;
            seed += prime;

            return min && max ? min + seed % maximum / maximum * (max - min) : seed % maximum / maximum;
            // if 'min' and 'max' are not provided, return random number between 0 & 1  
        }
    }
}

var rng = CustomRandom(09031887),
    //use '09031887' as a seed ?
    pre = document.getElementById('out');

pre.textContent += rng.next() + '\n';
pre.textContent += rng.next();
```

```html
<pre id="out"></pre>
```

[A further example of using the library that you linked to.](https://github.com/davidbau/seedrandom)

```js
Math.seedrandom(09031887);
//use '09031887' as a seed ?

var pre = document.getElementById('out');

pre.textContent += Math.random() + '\n'; // output always 0.21968861683194144
pre.textContent += Math.random(); // output always 0.9079655673042485
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/seedrandom/2.4.0/seedrandom.min.js"></script>
<pre id="out"></pre>
```

Comment: Very nice Xotic, I really appreaciate fixing the code, this changes a lot but I still need to change a couple of things.

1. The first one is to include the current-time and multiply it with the seed, not to use it as an "if".
2. The second one is to delay each following number by 1 second so the current-time will be different.

Comment: Also, the value for CustomRandom of 09031887 is my birth date and I am not sure if that is where it should go. And I need the numbers to be whole numbers from 1 to 50.

Comment: I tried the first answer where you fixed the code but it just generates the number 0.56 over and over.

Comment: It will if you use the same `seed` upon each generation.

Comment: Yes, correct, but what I want to do is to get a different number based on the seed which we obtain like this (current time * birth date) for example: 13:05:34 * 9/3/1987 which we write like this: 130534 * 931987. This is an example. And if we delay running the script for each different number by 1 second we get different results.

Comment: Then you will need to modify the code to do exactly that. Show us your modified code.

Comment: This is what I have done so far: https://jsfiddle.net/cunuqq7h/3/ but it doesn't work and I don't know why.

Comment: You still don't have any [event listeners](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to handle your user interface.

Comment: I am aware of that, I can add that later, I know how to do it :D

Comment: Do I even need this part?: "if 'min' and 'max' are not provided, return random number between 0 & 1" - Maybe I could remove this return safely?

Comment: I have came to an alternative using David Bau's seedrandom javascript: https://jsfiddle.net/cunuqq7h/5/ - I am not sure if the birth date is set in the right place but now the only thing I would need with this alternative is a way to convert each number to a whole number from 1 to 50 (min max) or something.

Answer (score 0):

This is as close as I got using David Bau's script (seedrandom.js):

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/seedrandom/2.4.0/seedrandom.min.js">
</script>
<b>Your birth date:</b><br>
Day: 
<select id="day">
<option selected="selected">day</option><option value="1">01</option><option value="2">02</option><option value="3">03</option><option value="4">04</option><option value="5">05</option><option value="6">06</option><option value="7">07</option><option value="8">08</option><option value="9">09</option><option>10</option><option>11</option><option>12</option><option>13</option><option>14</option><option>15</option><option>16</option><option>17</option><option>18</option><option>19</option><option>20</option><option>21</option><option>22</option><option>23</option><option>24</option><option>25</option><option>26</option><option>27</option><option>28</option><option>29</option><option>30</option><option>31</option>
</select>
Month:
<select id="month">
<option selected="selected">month</option><option value="1">01</option><option value="2">02</option><option value="3">03</option><option value="4">04</option><option value="5">05</option><option value="6">06</option><option value="7">07</option><option value="8">08</option><option value="9">09</option><option>10</option><option>11</option><option>12</option>
</select>
Year: 
<select id="year">
<option selected="selected">year</option><option>2015</option><option>2014</option><option>2013</option><option>2012</option><option>2011</option><option>2010</option><option>2009</option><option>2008</option><option>2007</option><option>2006</option><option>2005</option><option>2004</option><option>2003</option><option>2002</option><option>2001</option><option>2000</option><option>1999</option><option>1998</option><option>1997</option><option>1996</option><option>1995</option><option>1994</option><option>1993</option><option>1992</option><option>1991</option><option>1990</option><option>1989</option><option>1988</option><option>1987</option><option>1986</option><option>1985</option><option>1984</option><option>1983</option><option>1982</option><option>1981</option><option>1980</option><option>1979</option><option>1978</option><option>1977</option><option>1976</option><option>1975</option><option>1976</option><option>1975</option><option>1976</option><option>1975</option><option>1974</option><option>1973</option><option>1972</option><option>1971</option><option>1970</option><option>1969</option><option>1968</option><option>1967</option><option>1966</option><option>1965</option><option>1964</option><option>1963</option><option>1962</option><option>1961</option><option>1960</option>
</select>

<br><br>

<span id="nr1"></span> / 
<span id="nr2"></span> / 
<span id="nr3"></span> / 
<span id="nr4"></span> / 
<span id="nr5"></span> / 
<span id="nr6"></span> / 
<span id="nr7"></span> / 
<span id="nr8"></span> / 
<span id="nr9"></span> / 
<span id="nr10"></span>
<br><br>

<button onclick="generate()">Generate</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
function generate() {
    // get user's birth date as a number
    var day = (document.getElementById("day").value);
    var month = (document.getElementById("month").value);
    var year = (document.getElementById("year").value);
    var dob = (day+month+year);

    //check if user specified dob
    if(isNaN(day) || isNaN(month) || isNaN(year))
   {
    alert("Check your birth date!");
   }
    else {
    // Sets Math.random to an ARC4-based PRNG that is autoseeded using the
    // current time, dom state, and other accumulated local entropy.
    // The generated seed string is returned.
    Math.seedrandom();

    //the custom seed is the user's dob
    nr1.textContent = (Math.random(dob));
    nr2.textContent = (Math.random(dob));
    nr3.textContent = (Math.random(dob));
    nr4.textContent = (Math.random(dob));
    nr5.textContent = (Math.random(dob));
    nr6.textContent = (Math.random(dob));
    nr7.textContent = (Math.random(dob));
    nr8.textContent = (Math.random(dob));
    nr9.textContent = (Math.random(dob));
    nr10.textContent = (Math.random(dob));
   }
}
</script>
```

All I need now is to convert all the numbers into whole numbers ranging from 1 to 50 (something like min max). Anyone knows how to? > Feel free to use this: https://jsfiddle.net/cunuqq7h/9/